# MySQL select multiple values from one field

Tags: mysql

Not sure if this is possible but I have a schema like this:

```
id | user_id | thread_id 
1  | 1       | 1
2  | 4       | 1
3  | 1       | 2
4  | 3       | 2
```

I am trying to retrieve the thread_id where user_id = 1 and 4. I know that `in(1,4)` does not fit my needs as its pretty much a `OR` and will pull up record 3 as well and `Exists` only returns a bool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `JOIN` (that answer already exists) or `HAVING`, like this:

```
SELECT 
  thread_id, 
  COUNT(1) AS user_count 
FROM 
  t 
WHERE 
  user_id IN (1,4) 
GROUP BY
  thread_id
HAVING
  user_count=2
```

-check the [demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d4be/3). `HAVING` will fit better in case of many id's (because with `JOIN` you'll need to join as many times as many id you have). This is a bit tricky, however: you may do `=` comparison only if your records are unique per `(user_id, thread_id)`; for example, your `user_id` can repeat, then use `>=`, like in this [demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/610782/2).

Answer (score 0):

Try this with join, i guess you need to do AND operation with user_id must be 4 and 1 then

```
SELECT 
  t1.thread_id  
FROM
  TABLE t1 
  JOIN TABLE t2 
    ON (t1.user_id = t2.user_id) 
WHERE t1.user_id = 1 
  AND t2.user_id = 4
```